# cURL appears to be not working

Tags: php

I am trying to find out what my completed URL looks like when sending my xml file as a PARAM using cURL. However, I'm not seeing what cURL is creating for me to send to my java servlet on my apache tomcat server.

Any HELP/DIRECTION would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Here are my specs:

My $data:

```
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (5) {
  ["version"]=>
  string(3) "2.0"
  ["orderNo"]=>
  string(37) "sfly.000020513524-7001536_28935-tb.33"
  ["orderDate"]=>
  string(23) "2012-09-21 09:52:53 PDT"
  ["processing"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["statusCallback"]=>
    string(79) "http://orderfulfillment.shutterfly.com/ogateway-test/status/sfly/xpressdocs/
        "
  }
  ["suborders"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    ["suborder"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (7) {
      ["suborderNo"]=>
      string(5) "51917"
      ["deliveryEstimate"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) {
        ["earliest"]=>
        string(23) "2012-10-01 00:00:00 PDT"
        ["latest"]=>
        string(23) "2012-10-05 00:00:00 PDT"
      }
      ["greeting"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (2) {
        ["line1"]=>
        string(45) "Ordered for you by Andrew Mullen on 09/21/12."
        ["line2"]=>
        string(61) "Save 20% on Holiday Cards November 20 - 30 at Shutterfly
                "
      }
      ["shipAddr"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (8) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "burkina faso"
        ["address1"]=>
        string(17) "1234 burkina road"
        ["address2"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (0) {
        }
        ["city"]=>
        string(4) "yako"
        ["region"]=>
        string(3) "R21"
        ["postCode"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (0) {
        }
        ["countryCode"]=>
        string(2) "BF"
        ["countryName"]=>
        string(12) "Burkina Faso"
      }
      ["shipMethod"]=>
      string(7) "INTLSTD"
      ["additionalFulfillers"]=>
      string(5) "false"
      ["items"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {
        ["item"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (6) {
          ["itemNo"]=>
          string(2) "36"
          ["sku"]=>
          string(13) "6X8FLATCARD06"
          ["description"]=>
          string(39) "6x8 Stationery Card - Stacy Claire Boyd"
          ["quantity"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["product"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) {
            ["stationery"]=>
            object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (6) {
              ["formFactor"]=>
              string(3) "6x8"
              ["paperFinish"]=>
              string(5) "MATTE"
              ["orientation"]=>
              string(9) "LANDSCAPE"
              ["image"]=>
              object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (1) {
                ["location"]=>
                string(130) "http://orderfulfillment.shutterfly.com/fulfillment-test/image/1200/000020513524-7001536_28935--164044--315625--canvas.jpg
                                "
              }
              ["boc"]=>
              object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (1) {
                ["location"]=>
                string(130) "http://orderfulfillment.shutterfly.com/fulfillment-test/image/1200/000020513524-7001536_28935--164044--315626--canvas.jpg
                                "
              }
              ["copyright"]=>
              object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (1) {
                ["text"]=>
                string(13) "6X8FLATCARD06"
              }
            }
          }
          ["envelopes"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
            ["envelope"]=>
            object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (2) {
              ["toAddress"]=>
              object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (10) {
                ["font"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#21 (2) {
                  ["fontName"]=>
                  string(5) "Arial"
                  ["fontSize"]=>
                  string(2) "12"
                }
                ["name"]=>
                string(10) "FPO Tester"
                ["companyTitle"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#22 (0) {
                }
                ["address1"]=>
                string(16) "PSC 812 Box 2640"
                ["address2"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#23 (0) {
                }
                ["city"]=>
                string(3) "FPO"
                ["region"]=>
                string(2) "AE"
                ["postCode"]=>
                string(5) "09627"
                ["countryCode"]=>
                string(3) "USA"
                ["countryName"]=>
                string(24) "United States of America"
              }
              ["fromAddress"]=>
              object(SimpleXMLElement)#20 (10) {
                ["font"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#24 (2) {
                  ["fontName"]=>
                  string(5) "Arial"
                  ["fontSize"]=>
                  string(2) "12"
                }
                ["name"]=>
                string(13) "Andrew Mullen"
                ["companyTitle"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#25 (0) {
                }
                ["address1"]=>
                string(22) "2333 W. El Moro Circle"
                ["address2"]=>
                object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (0) {
                }
                ["city"]=>
                string(4) "Mesa"
                ["region"]=>
                string(2) "AZ"
                ["postCode"]=>
                string(5) "85202"
                ["countryCode"]=>
                string(3) "USA"
                ["countryName"]=>
                string(24) "United States of America"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My $url = 'http://melinda.xpressdocs.com/PostHandler';

Here is my code:

```
    function postToUrl($url, $data) {

    $post = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $value = curl_getinfo($post);
    var_dump($value);
    exit;

    $result = curl_exec($post);

    curl_close($post);
}
```

Results of var_dump:

```
    array(20) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(42) "http://melinda.xpressdocs.com/PostHandler/"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
}
```

Comment: "http://melinda.xpressdocs.com/PostHandler" is not a valid URL ....  see http://validator.w3.org/checklink?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmelinda.xpressdocs.com%2FPostHandler&summary=on&hide_type=all&depth=&check=Check

Comment: What happens when you remove the `exit;` that you are not expecting to happen?

Comment: Well, what kind of information are you looking for?

Comment: What info are expecting to see before executing the request?

Comment: Can you give a dump of the data you're trying to send?

Comment: I am trying to see the param that contains the xml that I'm passing in the $data variable associated with the POSTFIELDS.  I assumed that it would be sent in a PARAM that I am trying to send along with the URL that I'm posting to.  Sorry I don't know PHP that well.  I am just trying to POST the xml to a URL whereby my servlet then takes over on tomcat.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Melinda `curl_getinfo()` will not show you the message body, if you want to see it just `echo $data;`. Or do you not trust cURL to do what you tell it to?

Comment: I've seen the data before I sent it into the curl option. I'll post my xml above.  Sorry I did not know that you needed to see the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Set **CURLOPT_VERBOSE** to true to see what cURL is doing

Comment: Sorry, do I set that in the section where I'm setting all the other curl options?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, set it with the other options.

Comment: When I put int he CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true then I got the same $result value as I have stipulated above.  Thank for the help.

Comment: You'll get the same result, the idea was to see what happened, what headers are sent / received and what data is being posted.

Comment: Obviously, I'm confused.  My apologies.  Where is the PARAM that contains my xml data that is being appended to the URL in the http request or I'm assuming is being appended to the URL.  If cURL wants the data where is it putting it?  Thank you.

Comment: In your code you're setting the data, $data, using the option CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. This will not append the data to the url, it will POST the data to the given URL.

Comment: Thanks, Lixeno.  The objective that I am trying to meet is to post to a given URL the XML data into the http request. So that I can take the xml info from that request and post the response to my local tomcat log.  That was it.  I apparently misunderstood how to use cURL.  Is there way to do what I'm trying to accomplish in PHP.  Thanks.